# Doing "project>Debug>Start new instance" of an another project in the same solution through c# code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to do this, visual studio " **project>Debug>Start new instance**."

Do this through **c# code**?

I mean starting 2nd project which is in the sample solution through a function in 1st project.

say, I have 2 projects,

```
                #project 1

                #project 2, both are in same solution.
```

There is a function in **#project 1**,

say,

```
          public void startproject2()

            {
             //code for doing "project>Debug>Start new instance" #project 2

             }
```

Is there a way to do that through **c# code**?

Comment: So do you mean run as two executables? So say both your projects were forms, do you want two forms open? If so, you can compile the second project and run using [`Process.Start("path/to/the/compiled/exe")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Comment: I have a function in #project 1 which need to start project 2, then, a function in #project 2 is hit, a function in #project 2 is hit, pass the data as parameter to a function in #project1

Comment: In that case, it actually sounds like you want to look in to making project 2 a library project and then you can include it like other libraries in to project 1 and call functions within it from your first project.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to debug 2 projects at the same time.

To do that, just right click on the solution and select **Set Startup Projects...**.
There you can select the projects that should be started and debugged if you press *F5* to debug.

Comment: I want that function in project 2 to be started only at a particular event

Comment: This doesn't work, and seriously, I can't think of any scenario where you would need that.